# How to add new key value to yaml without overwriting it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I have small python script which responsible for updating my yaml file by adding new records:

```
data = yaml.load(file)
data['WIN']['Machine'] = dict(node_labels='+> tfs vs2022')
data['WIN']['Machine'] = dict(vs='vs2022')
yaml.dump(data, file)
```

Every time when I run above script I will get updated yaml file like below:

```
WIN:
  Machine:
    vs: vs2022
```

My desired output to have both my key: value pairs

```
WIN:
  Machine:
    node_labels: +> tfs vs2022
    vs: vs2022
```

I'm wondering why line `data['WIN'][nodeName] = dict(node_labels='+> tfs vs2022')` overwritten by next line?  How can add several key: values for `Machine` section?

Comment: "I'm wondering why line `data['WIN'][nodeName] = dict(node_labels='+> tfs vs2022')` overwritten by next line?"—because that's what the code does. The next line creates a brand new dictionary and assigns it to that key. What is your desired output?

Comment: my desired output is to have both my key:value (node_labels='+> tfs vs2022') and (vs='vs2022')

Comment: `data['WIN']['Machine'] = dict(node_labels='+> tfs vs2022', vs='vs2022')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a YAML related problem, but a conceptual problem in your non-yaml related Python code.

By assigning a dict as value to the key `Machine`, you **set** that value. By assigning
another dict to the key, you overwrite that value completely, erasing the previous key-value pair.

If you simplify your code:

```py
data = dict(Machine=None)
data['Machine'] = dict(node_labels='+> tfs vs2022')
print('data 1', data)
data['Machine'] = dict(vs='vs2022')
print('data 2', data)
```

As you can see after the second assignment, the key `node_labels` is no longer available.

```
data 1 {'Machine': {'node_labels': '+> tfs vs2022'}}
data 2 {'Machine': {'vs': 'vs2022'}}
```

There are several ways to solve this. You can either assign a value to a key in the first dict:

```py
data = dict(Machine=None)
data['Machine'] = added_dict = dict(node_labels='+> tfs vs2022')
print('data 1', data)
added_dict['vs'] ='vs2022'
print('data 2', data)
```

Now you have both keys in the second output:

```
data 1 {'Machine': {'node_labels': '+> tfs vs2022'}}
data 2 {'Machine': {'node_labels': '+> tfs vs2022', 'vs': 'vs2022'}}
```

If you don't already know there is a dict where you can add a key to, you might to use `.setdefault`,
either using key-value assigment, and/or by using `.update` (useful for updating multiple keys in one go):

```py
data = dict()
data.setdefault('Machine', {})['node_labels'] = '+> tfs vs2022'
print('data 1', data)
data.setdefault('Machine', {}).update(dict(vs='vs2022'))
print('data 2', data)
```

```
data 1 {'Machine': {'node_labels': '+> tfs vs2022'}}
data 2 {'Machine': {'node_labels': '+> tfs vs2022', 'vs': 'vs2022'}}
```

Of course you can put `node_labels` and `vs` in one dict and assign, but that would overwrite any existing key-values loaded
from YAML. So the use of `.update` is IMO better:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

file_in = Path('input.yaml')
# key in YAML mapping with null value
file_in.write_text("""\
WIN:
""")
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(file_in)
if data['WIN'] is None:
    data['WIN'] = {}
data['WIN'].setdefault('Machine', {}).update(dict(node_labels='+> tfs vs2022'))
data['WIN'].setdefault('Machine', {}).update(dict(vs='vs2022'))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives your expected result:

```
WIN:
  Machine:
    node_labels: +> tfs vs2022
    vs: vs2022
```